# Laser triangulation via mirror

Tags: reflection, laser

if I use a triangulation sensor and put a perferctly flat mirror in front of it (45°), will the measured distance be the same as without a mirror?[image]

Answer (score 0):

It should, as long as your mirror is large enough to capture all the rays and you indeed have good alignment! Of course the alignment will be critical, so this is probably not recommended if you can avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

The distance measured by the sensor will be the sum of the distances approaching and leaving the mirror.